# How to set Jenkins parameter in build.xml, and use it in testng for multiple classes

Tags: ant, testng, build.xml

I have been using multiple testng files in my `build.xml` like in the example shown below:

```
<target name="run1" depends="compile">
  <!-- config testng -->
    <xmlfileset dir="." includes="test1.xml" />
    <sysproperty key="testurl" value="${url}" />
    <sysproperty Key="dryruntest" value="${name}" />
    <!--<sysproperty key="logLevel" value="${testLogLevel}"/> -->
  </testng>
  <fail if="test.failure" message="Not all tests passed!" />
</target>
<target name="run2" depends="compile">
    <xmlfileset dir="." includes="test2.xml" />
    <sysproperty key="testurl" value="${url}" />
    <sysproperty Key="dryruntest" value="${name}" />
    <!--<sysproperty key="logLevel" value="${testLogLevel}"/> -->
  </testng>
  <fail if="test.failure" message="Not all tests passed!" />
</target>
```

But now I want to use just one `testng.xml` in both the target tabs in `build.xml`, for which I need the `commontestng.xml` to look like this:

[image: Sample]

When I kick off the job from Jenkin (which currently takes in one custom argument - which is `url`) and target name for `build.xml`, it works fine with different testng for respective target names in `build.xml`.

However, when I try to use a single testng file in `build.xml` for different target names it always runs the `test1`, and not `test2`.